# Pandas time diff: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

When I try to calculate de difference between date series and today I get `Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones` error.

Loading data

```
raw_data = pd.read_json('resultados_finales_completos10000.json')
print(raw_data['fecha_publicacion'][0])
```

> 2017-09-24T15:04:22.000Z

Turn object type column to datetime

```
raw_data['fecha_publicacion'] =  pd.to_datetime(raw_data['fecha_publicacion'])
print(raw_data['fecha_publicacion'][0])
print(raw_data['fecha_publicacion'][0].tzinfo, type(today.tzinfo))
```

> 2017-09-24 15:04:22+00:00

> UTC <class 'datetime.timezone'>

Then I set today's value

```
today = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
print(today)
print(today.tzinfo, type(today.tzinfo))
```

> 2021-08-13 21:31:16.031605+00:00

> UTC <class 'datetime.timezone'>

In both cases I have the same timezone settings.

Finaly I'm trying to create a new column to store the time difference as follows and get the fore mentioned error.

```
raw_data['meses_venta'] = today - raw_data['fecha_publicacion']
```

I tryied the following posts with not much success. Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402370/timestamp-subtraction-must-have-the-same-timezones-or-no-timezones)
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254408/timestamp-subtraction-of-time-arrays-with-different-timezones)
- [Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198068/how-to-remove-timezone-from-a-timestamp-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
- [Post 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736569/timestamp-subtraction-must-have-the-same-timezones-or-no-timezones-but-they-are)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of your MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the same timezone or (no timezone) as the error says.

One way to do so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pandas as pd
x = pd.to_datetime('2017-09-24T15:04:22.000Z')
today = datetime.now(tz=x.tz)

today - x # Timedelta('1419 days 06:59:48.134906')
```